# Replacing `:` with `-` while doing an `INSERT` statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to move some data into a program but the name field does not accept the `:` character. I would like to change the `:` to a `-` while doing the `INSERT` statement. The data I am moving is something like this "Revenue:A". I would like it to be "Revenue-A" when I move it.

I have tried the `REPLACE` statement in a nested `SELECT` statement with no luck. I have researched using a char index statement but do not understand how to make it change the code.

```
SELECT Account
  , 'Accounts Receivable'
  , (SELECT REPLACE([DESC], '%:%', '-'))
  , (Select REPLACE(Account + ' - ' + [DESC], '%:%', '-'))
  , ………
FROM ………
WHERE ………
```

The results that I get still include the `:`. When I try the code without the wildcard character it just returns `-` as the name, which will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `select` statements if the columns `[DESC]` and `Account` are columns from table(s) mentioned in your query:

```
  ,REPLACE([DESC], ':', '-')
  ,0,0
  ,REPLACE(Account + ' - ' + [DESC],':','-')
```

I removed `%` from the argument `':'` (if you used it as a wildcard it does not work and it is not needed).